# Instead of the left open brace, if I want an Arrow mark, how I can do it?

Tags: arrows, arrays, cases

```
\begin{cases}
First line\\
Second line\\
third line\\
\vdots

\end{cases}
```

is giving like,
[image]

> Instead of the left open brace, if I want an Arrow mark, how I can do it?

One way is this,

```
$\left\uparrow \begin{array}{l}
First line\\
Second line\\
third line\\
\vdots
\end{array}
\right.$
```

which gives like

[image]

But the arrow is looking thin..I want a thick(may be ultrathick and in some colors) arrow.

> If there is any other shapes I can draw means i will be happy..

How to do that??

---

After getting some comments,
I am linking [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280107/how-to-set-floating-option-for-bclogo), which also narrates my problem.

Comment: I am sorry for not accepting that answers because I didnt get what exactly I want??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with thick arrow and some colors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{smartdiagram}
\begin{document}
\smartdiagram[priority descriptive diagram]{%
Third line, 
Second line, 
First line}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Oh..Its awesome..thank you so much...any other diagrams like this..can you give me link for the collections..@fran..

Comment: @David: http://texdoc.net/pkg/smartdiagram

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a double arrow helps?

```
$\left\Uparrow \begin{array}{l}
First line\\
Second line\\
third line\\
\vdots
\end{array}
\right.$
```

[image: output 1]

Colour is also possible:

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
...
$\color{blue}\left\Uparrow \color{black}\begin{array}{l}
First line\\
Second line\\
third line\\
\vdots
\end{array}
\right.$
```

[image: output 2]