# How to set floating option for bclogo?

Tags: floats, wrap, bclogo

I am asking this question may be extension of [this question.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278180/instead-of-the-left-open-brace-if-i-want-an-arrow-mark-how-i-can-do-it?noredirect=1#comment674795_278180)
 I wish to use some other symbols otherthan leftbrace in my older question. And, recently I come to know that `bclogo` solves that problem.
but while working with that `bclogo` I am finding the following  difficulty.
That in some cases I couldn't find the `bclogo` output in the same page.

for example, with the following codes, i will get the texts in one page and the `bclogo` in the next page.

I am expecting it has to be running text only..

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}    
\lipsum[1]
\begin{bclogo}{Code}
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item     
\item 
\item\item \item \item \item\item \item  
\item \item \item \item item \item \item 
\item \item \item \item     
\end{itemize}    
\end{bclogo}%    
\end{document}
```

### My output:

[Click here for the output image file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B62JR2iJ8Ep_MzBuSnNrMnJxVUE/view)

> My aim is `bclogo` has to be in 1st page itself or it should start with 1st page and ends with its position.

Comment: Are you asking how the `bclogo` box can be split across the page break?

Comment: exactly..but it has to automatically..@Thruston

Comment: You can't do it automatically with normal LaTeX minipages, which is what `bclogo` appears to use.  You would have find a solution that used one of the ideas discussed in [this question about breakable vboxes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20901/breakable-vboxes).